# When does the browser execute JavaScript that sits in the cache?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-cache

I was just wondering at what point the browser executes JavaScript when it comes from the cache. Even though I did some research, I somehow couldn't find any satisfactory answers.

Suppose I have a site, where I put all my JS in one file, which I include just before the closing body-tag.

Now, if the cache is empty, the JS gets loaded after (most of) the content has already been downloaded, and then executed (unless I'd use a method to defer execution).

But if I go to the next page, the JS is in the cache. Will it get executed right after the styles are applied to the HTML? In that case, the UI -might- freeze up during download of the content, if I'm not mistaken.

Hope I'm not wracking my brain over something obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading from the web or using the cache should give you the same results. The moment the browser sees the script tag on the second page, it will call the cache and execute it. If you also insert the script tag right before closing the body tag on the second page, you will get the same result.

Comment: Reading your answers it occures to me that somehow I was implying that the browser knows the script would be used on every page of the site, which it doesn't of course. It has to wait until it sees a script tag. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

When it reads it from the `script` tags. So it will still wait until getting to the bottom of the page if you put your script tags there.